clipPath a container
i want to bend the right hand side on a container
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

   class RoundedDiagonalPathClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0.0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0.0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0.0, size.width - 20.0, 0.0)
      ..lineTo(40.0, 70.0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(10.0, 85.0, 0.0, 120.0)
      ..close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}

what i was able to achieved



I've never done this before, but it looks like you'll need another quadraticBezierTo at the end of that path. Did you try that already?

can you give the code, i have been trying i am not getting it @puf-FrankvanPuffelen

@puf-FrankvanPuffelen i have update the code and what i achieved

Use this,
Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 40)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 40, 10)
      ..lineTo(size.width - 20, size.height / 2)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          size.width, (size.height / 2) + 5, size.width, (size.height / 2) + 30)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..close();
    return path;

Adjust corners and slant as required.
